# How can I automatically create an adress parameter upon sign up with Devise (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm currently trying to automatically create an user_address (which will be a randomly generated hash, which is for now hardcoded) string upon sign-up with the Ruby on Rails devise Gem. I have added the user_address to the list of allowed parameters I am currently trying to add this logic to the *registrations_controller.rb* by adding the following method :

```
def create
  super do
   current_user.user_address = '1F1tAaz5x1HUXrCNLbtMDqcw6o5GNn4xqX'
 end
end
```

I suppose this is because current_user must not be defined before the actual POST (create user) has been processed but I am not sure about the way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: so the user address will be auto generated on create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly (I think I do) you could move away from trying to do this in the create action in the controller and instead use a model callback on the User model.. that way its automatically created when a user registers.

example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

      before_create :assign_user_address
      validates_uniqueness_of :user_address

      def assign_user_address
        begin
          self.user_address = SecureRandom.hex
          other_user = User.find_by(user_address: self.user_address)
        end while other_user
      end

end
```

the before_create will generate the user_address and assign it to the user that is registering, while the validates_uniqueness_of ensures that you will never have a duplicate user address all in one fell swoop (although with a random string the chances of duplicating are slim.. but better to be safe than sorry.. I find this method super easy and keeps your controller clean and un cluttered.

Let me know if this wasn't what you were looking for..

Comment: No problem at all! Glad it helped you out!